# Iterate a circle which located at specific degree from a degree.

Tags: circles, angle

I have a angle: Angle(x, y).
I want to iterate a circle which located at a distance of specific degree. I easily can do it by x or y axis only.
For example:
Offset from Angle(x, y) is 6 degree. Step is 1 degree.
Angle(x + (-3..3), y) or Angle(x, y + (-3..3))
It is only by vertically or horizontally, I don't know how combine x and y to make a circle.
[Here is a picture which will help to understand what exactly I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d417n.png)

Comment: I do not understand the picture. What do "offset" and "step" mean? What does "combine $x$ and $y$ to make a circle" mean? What does "iterate" mean? Please [edit] the question and the picture to explain more clearly. Label the picture with numbers from the problem. Fill in tht ? with what you want to see. Tell us what this is for.

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.